# Inversion in second conditional

Tags: inversion

If Sandy were giving a speech tomorrow, she would be very nervous. 
Were Sandy giving a speech tomorrow, she would be very nervous. 
Is this inversion correct?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Note that such inversions are very rare and archaic; nobody talks this way any more.

Comment: Were Sandy to be giving a speech tomorrow, she would be very nervous. (I think this inversion is better) Am I right?

Comment: No to your last comment. It's fine, but it's certainly not *better*. To me, *were to be* is awkward—the *to be* is unnecessary.